# Cascading select options in angular

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I cannot get cascading dropdown selects to work pas the first one in angular. On selecting the first option, if it has values for *divisions* I'd like to show them in the second dropdown, and if the latter has values for *workplaces* I'd like to show them in the third.

Here is my html

```
<div ng-controller="SectorController">
<select class="form-control" id="businessUnit" ng-model="divisionsSource" 
            ng-options="businessUnit.division as businessUnit.sectorName for businessUnit in businessUnits track by businessUnit.id">
                <option value=''>Select</option>
            </select>

        <td>
          <select class="form-control" id="division" ng-model="workplacesSource" ng-disabled="!divisionsSource"
          ng-options="division.workplace as division.sectorName for division in divisionsSource track by division.id">
            <option value=''>Select</option>
          </select>

          <select class="form-control" id="workplace" ng-disabled="!workplacesSource || !divisionsSource" ng-model="workplace">
          <option value=''>Select</option> 
          <option ng-repeat="workplace in workplacesSource" value='{{workplace}}'>{{workplace}}</option>
          </select>
```

and here is my json feed:

```
$rootScope.businessUnits = [
                      {
                        "id": 1,
                        "sectorName": "AAA",
                        "sectorLevel": 20
                      },
                      {
                        "id": 2,
                        "sectorName": "BBB",
                        "sectorLevel": 20
                      },
                      {
                        "id": 3,
                        "sectorName": "CCC",
                        "sectorLevel": 20
                      },
                      {
                        "id": 4,
                        "sectorName": "DDD",
                        "sectorLevel": 20,
                        "divisions": [
                          {
                            "id": 6,
                            "sectorName": "DDD1",
                            "sectorLevel": 30
                          },
                          {
                            "id": 7,
                            "sectorName": "DDD2",
                            "sectorLevel": 30
                          },
                          {
                            "id": 8,
                            "sectorName": "DDD3",
                            "sectorLevel": 30
                          },
                          {
                            "id": 9,
                            "sectorName": "DDD4",
                            "sectorLevel": 30,
                            "workplaces": [
                              {
                                "id": 12,
                                "sectorName": "DDD4 SUB1",
                                "sectorLevel": 40
                              },
                              {
                                "id": 13,
                                "sectorName": "DDD4 SUB2",
                                "sectorLevel": 40
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            "id": 10,
                            "sectorName": "DDD5",
                            "sectorLevel": 30
                          },
                          {
                            "id": 11,
                            "sectorName": "DDD6",
                            "sectorLevel": 30
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "id": 5,
                        "sectorName": "EEE",
                        "sectorLevel": 20
                      }
                    ]
```

Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code which you wrote??? Where is it getting wrong?

Comment: Why are you using rootScope to store that json data?

Comment: That's my code up there ashfaq.p. It is just populating the first select option. I am using rootScope to store that value to access it wherever I want, Joe. Is that bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ng-options aren't correct. Here's a plunkr which fixes it: http://plnkr.co/edit/GOIiGXAHnr7nUfv4NHVH?p=preview

Explanations:

```
businessUnit.division as businessUnit.sectorName 
for businessUnit in businessUnits track by businessUnit.id
```

So, when an option is selected in this first select box, its model (`divisionsSource`) is set to the selected `businessUnit`'s division. But a `businessUnit` doesn't have a field named `division`. It has a field named `divisions`.

So the code should be

```
businessUnit as businessUnit.sectorName 
for businessUnit in businessUnits track by businessUnit.id
```

and the next select box should use

```
division as division.sectorName 
for division in divisionsSource.divisions track by division.id
```

Comment: Merci JB, I'm really impressed by your answer and how fast you provided it.